# Can I travel to European countries with the Irish passport and without destination Visa?

Tags: schengen, passports, schengen-visas, ireland, passport-stamps

I know that Ireland is in the European Union but not in the Schengen Area.

My question is when I get my Irish passport, can I travel to countries in Europe (or most of them that are in Schengen Area) only with my Irish passport and not taking the destination's Visa?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can since you are a EU citizen. That has nothing to do with the Schengen Area. There is no immigration control for EU Citizens, only checks that you are a EU Citizen. That is why no enter/exit stamps are stamped in the passport.

Comment: Wait a moment -- are you getting an **Irish passport** (that is, becoming a citizen of Ireland), or merely a **visa for Ireland**? Those are extremely different things. Your [other question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19171/how-can-i-take-blue-card-in-spain) says you're living in Spain with a D visa, which (a) should not be possible if you're _already_ an Irish citizen, and (b) would probably make it hard to naturalize as an Irishman since you're not resident in that country. (And your profile says you're in Iran ...)

Comment: @HenningMakholm :)), my StackExchange profile is old. Right now I live in Spain but I'm considering to relocate to Ireland for living and working; But on the other hand, I'm researching other possibilities like the EU Blue Card. For example, maybe it's better to stay here a little bit more, then take the Blue Card, and after that relocate; But for this possibility, I have some questions which I've asked on the other one.

Comment: @Dr.jacky: Relocating to Ireland won't make you an Irish citizen, so you wouldn't get an Irish passport.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But if I live and work there for 5 years, I can apply for citizenship by naturalisation: https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/irish_citizenship/becoming_an_irish_citizen_through_naturalisation.html

Comment: @Dr.jacky I am confused by your use of the words "When I got my Irish passport" in your question, and your works in the comment above that if you live and work there for 5 years you can _apply_ for citizenship there by naturalization. So I will ask directly: are you now an Irish citizen? If not, not all the Answers below will apply to you at this time.

Comment: @David looks like this is currently a hypothetical question in the future with [the unreal past](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/unreal-past/): "*This is often the case in conditional sentences when we are talking about a hypothetical situation that might exist now or at any time.*"

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, I'm not an Irish citizen. I want to go to Ireland by work visa, then live and work there for at least 5 years, then apply for citizenship.

Comment: I think it's 6 years now, they changed it recently.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane Would you please give us a link to this new change?

Comment: @KeithLoughnane I've checked again on the Department of Justice and Equality's website and it's still 5 years: http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/WP16000022#non-eu-eea-swiss

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should read up on your rights as an EU citizen. They are extensive.

- As an Irish citizen, you can not just travel but also work in the EU without a visa. You can bring your dependents if they're not Irish as well, who get simplified visa procedures.
- If you are resident in other EU countries, you can (and should) vote in the European and some local elections.
- You can get consular support from other EU embassies abroad if there is no Irish one.

Comment: With an Irish passport you are an Irish, and as such an EU, citizen. And all things that goes for other Irish citizens goes for you.

Comment: It's assuming that they do not hold Irish citizenship.

Comment: @HankyPanky, edited.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer to your question is ‘yes’.

Irish citizens have visa-free or visa on arrival access to 185 countries and territories; the international access available to Irish citizens ranks 6th in the world according to the Visa Restrictions Index. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_passport

You can check which countries you will require a visa for here https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php Notable European exceptions are Turkey (e-visa) and Russia.

Comment: So, these topics that talking about getting Schengen Visa of the destination before the travel is only for non-EU people?

Comment: @Dr.jacky yes, this insures that they don't get 'stranded' in the recieving country.